# Confluent Kafka Connect Docker Container Issue

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using the following docker compose snippet:

```
connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
```

The container appears to start up just fine however when I then try and add a HDFS sink connection via the connect container REST API:

```
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data \
@confluent_hdfs.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Where the confluent_hdfs.json file contains:

```
{
  "name": "hdfs-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://localhost:9000",
    "flush.size": "1000",
    "name": "hdfs-sink"
  }
}
```

I am getting a 500 HTTP response. Inspecting the logs for the connector container shows:

```
WARN /connectors (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel)
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
io/confluent/connect/hdfs/HdfsSinkConnectorConfig
```

From checking this issue I see the following post:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/273

Which suggested that the plugin path was wrong. As far as I can tell however I have set this correctly to /usr/share/java and I also see correctly configured symbolic links that this post alludes to.

Further, when performing the request:

```
curl http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins
```

I see the following response:

```
[
{"class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"4.1.1"},
{"class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.tools.SchemaSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"1.1.1-cp1"},
{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"1.1.1-cp1"},
{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"1.1.1-cp1"}
]
```

So I'm not really sure if I missed something in the compose file or I am missing something else here?

Comment: Have a look there for an example https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo/blob/4.1.1-post/docker-compose.yml However even with this, it looks like you are missing things from your image. Maybe you haven't pulled 4.1.1? Try pulling that explicitly and validating what exists in /usr/share/java in the container

Comment: `hdfs.url": "hdfs://localhost:9000` Assumes HDFS is available on the same container as Kafka Connect, which is not the case for those Docker images

Comment: Hi there, apologies for this - I picked a poor example for the location of my filesystem. You are completely right - in reality my code had a remote url not within the same container. Again - sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dawsaw I worked through the example you suggested and I realised that the issue was with a connector plugin I was installing by mounting the connector folder as a volume. Unfortunately I mounted the connector in the wrong part of the connect container which appeared to compromise the ability of the container to operate correctly.

What I had working by the end was:

```
connect:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:4.1.1
container_name: connect
restart: always
ports:
  - "8083:8083"
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
  - kafka
volumes:
  - $PWD/confluentinc-kafka-connect-rabbitmq-1.0.0-preview:/usr/share/java/confluentinc-kafka-connect-rabbitmq-1.0.0-preview
environment:
  CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
  CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
  CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
  CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "connect"
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-config
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-offsets
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-status
  CONNECT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
  CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java"
```

Thanks again for the help with this and apologies about the poor example snippet created initially.